# Struggling to understand why two different definitions of Baire Category theorem are same

Tags: real-analysis

I have two versions of Baire Category theorem and I am struggling to find why they are equivalent:
My professor notes says " Any complete metric space is of second category i.e. we cannot write it as countable union of nowhere dense subsets".

Online article I read says " If M is complete metric space, If $D_{n}$ is any countable collection of open dense sets in X then $\cap D_{n}$ is dense in X.

I have understood both the proofs but I am not getting how this two are same thing only. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall \{C_n\}$ : subsets of $X$ s.t. $\forall n,int(\bar{C_n})=\emptyset$, $\cup_n C_n\neq X$

$\Leftrightarrow_{(1)}\forall\{C_n\}$ : **closed** subsets of $X$ s.t. $\forall n,int(C_n)=\emptyset$, $\cup_n C_n\neq X$

$\Leftrightarrow_{(2)}\forall\{U_n\}$ : open subsets of $X$ s.t. $\forall n,\bar{U_n}=X$, $\cap_n U_n\neq\emptyset$

$\Leftrightarrow_{(3)}\forall\{U_n\}$ : open subsets of $X$ s.t. $\forall n,\bar{U_n}=X$, $\forall V\subset X$ : open, $(\cap_n U_n)\cap V\neq\emptyset$

and so we are done

---

[Reasoning]

(1) $\Rightarrow$ is trivial. $\Leftarrow$ : can be shown by putting closure to each subset $C_n$ on the first statement.

(2) can be shown simply by taking $C_n,U_n$ as complements.

(3) $\Leftarrow$ is trivial. To show $\Rightarrow$, you consider a new countable collection $\{U_n\}\cup\{V\}$.

Comment: Only if my understanding of your hint is correct, then in (3), new countable collection should be ${U_{n}}\cap{V}$ for each n